# How can I test if visit monitoring is working in my iOS app? (Using startMonitoringVisits api)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, core-location, cllocationmanager

I'm developing a location journaling app for iPhone, and I'm trying to use the new visit monitoring API for iOS 8. I've read the Xcode documentation and watched a [WWDC 2014 Video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=706), and I think I've properly implemented the startMonitoringVisits and didVisit methods. However, I'd like to find out if they are actually working before I build the rest of the app.

How can I find out if my app is receiving visit data? Is there a way I can use the iPhone simulator in Xcode to test visit events? Or do I have to actually go walking around, stopping in different places and waiting for a visit to register?

I'd really appreciate it if any code examples are in Swift, as I'm more comfortable with it, but I don't want to be too demanding, so don't hesitate if you have some Objective-C examples.

Thanks.

Edit: I originally asked if visit monitoring works when Frequent Locations are turned off in Settings > Privacy > Location Services > System Services. I've done some testing, and the answer is yes visit monitoring works even if the user has turned off Frequent Locations. That setting seems to be just for built-in visit tracking, like in the Maps app.

Comment: Hi... did you get any success on how to test visit monitoring?

Comment: Not with the iPhone simulators in Xcode, but I've found some work-arounds. I went out and walked around and figured out that startMonitoringVisits and didVisit work for my app. I edited my didVisit method to save a file with an array of CLVisits. Then I went out again and generated and saved a bunch of CLVisits. Then I imported them to my Mac, and when I need to see how my app processes them, I manually call didVisit and use a pre-generated CLVisit as an argument. That only helps me test the code in didVisit though, not the whole callback process.

Comment: @ConfusedByCode The WWDC video was really helpful in understanding the visit location service